# Fade out animation of a ListViews itemRows one after the other

Tags: android, listview, animation, fadeout, listitem

I have a listView that 6 itemRows fade in ( animate) onStart.

I want them to fade out individually but as a newbie endedup doing it like this.
The Timer and handler method had seemed okay but had no means to do the six views separately after a time interval of 200ms.

Please if someone could suggest a better way.

```
private void doLVAnimIndicator() {

                mLevelslist.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indicator_bg_btn);
                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indicator_bg_btn);
                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indicator_bg_btn);
                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indicator_bg_btn);
                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indicator_bg_btn);
                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(5).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.indicator_bg_btn); 
                    }
                }, 160);

                mLevelslist.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                 mLevelslist.getChildAt(5).setBackgroundResource(R.color.outline);   
                    }
                }, 1300);

                mLevelslist.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(4).setBackgroundResource(R.color.outline);
                    }
                }, 1375);

                mLevelslist.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(3).setBackgroundResource(R.color.outline);
                    }
                }, 1450);

                mLevelslist.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(2).setBackgroundResource(R.color.outline);
                    }
                }, 1525);

                mLevelslist.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.color.outline);
                    }
                }, 1600);

                mLevelslist.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mLevelslist.getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.color.outline);
                    }
                }, 1675);

         return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an AlphaAnimation and the View.startAnimation method to animate the views.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    AlphaAnimation a = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    a.setDuration(<duration>)
    a.setStartOffset(i * duration + i * offset);
    mLevelslist.getChildAt(i).startAnimation(a);
}
```

Comment: Good reply, some helpful code but I am not using it in a loop using an _i_, hence the itemrows line by line.

Comment: It was just to give you an idea about how to use the animation.